# Jquery - JSON iteration and display

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I am looking to parse the JSON file that jquery is getting from my backend Flask.

Problem: I would like to display all JSON objects provided from the backend in human readible fashion, with ability to remove/format how I display it by accessing each JSON block and value sepparately. Displaying each JSON block/search with values of choice in separate block.

I am making API call from another source yummly.com. Please find code below:

```
def yummly_search(str):
    """

    :type str: str
    """

    final_url = 'https://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=d3eb5115&_app_key=c14b1b2ac6023a3b735a9c290b4c7f5e&q='+str+'&requirePictures=true&allowedAllergy[]=393^Gluten-Free&allowedAllergy[]=392^Wheat-Free'
    r = requests.get(final_url, verify=True)

    json_obj = r.json()

    return json.dumps(json_obj['matches'])
```

How backend is passing JSON to jquery:

```
@app.route('/background_process')
def background_process():
    try:
        lang = request.args.get('input_search', 0, type=str)
        if lang:
            return jsonify(result=yummly_search(lang))
        else:
            return jsonify(result='Try again.')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

This is how I handle my Jquery - using jquery to dynamically update the frontend for user convenience:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/background_process', {
              input_search: $('input[name="input_search"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
              $("#result").text(data.result)
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
    </script>
```

What is being displayed at the moment in browser (sample of 2 json objects displayed but the list usually involves 5+ objects):

```
[{"imageUrlsBySize": {"90": "http://lh5.ggpht.com/UwNbjIdEdFmkETuO0pjnBvhuPkgXVskHco3qA5lV1xInenr6jiXt3zljBt9-TptV_oi-xcG_TQuS3dltp-gURQ=s90-c"}, "sourceDisplayName": "Witty in the City", "ingredients": ["chicken thighs", "dijon mustard", "maple syrup", "rice vinegar", "fresh rosemary", "salt", "pepper"], "id": "Man-Pleasing-Chicken-608913", "smallImageUrls": ["http://lh4.ggpht.com/gInMhsmcQ708LZAw4ryeheSm6cOuvDtlzpHpbrE1RW01kYudZlWoRBcEiS-gj_2mj_8Xdl-dzgNY2CJxbHbT=s90"], "recipeName": "Man-Pleasing Chicken", "totalTimeInSeconds": 3300, "attributes": {"course": ["Main Dishes"]}, "flavors": null, "rating": 3}, {"imageUrlsBySize": {"90": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/IDz7Q2v10M0sEFOBweyTZp2vXitaSxzVdsCUqTV9-sMaTY7APmO06n8-YzAyg5T-FZniNJi5y_WlWILe1osQJFY=s90-c"}, "sourceDisplayName": "Jo Cooks", "ingredients": ["chicken breasts", "enchilada sauce", "corn tortillas", "monterey jack"], "id": "Easy-Chicken-Enchilada-Casserole-2233185", "smallImageUrls": ["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VsCGpuAxn4TXkAbB46_Ae0FT_GY3qzFjLgtIitk5JcBt0TAukogXhSoPTUH70uU4qKQ698SxUKAUQ5u5slSCQA=s90"],
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Update thanks to  Barmar@:

Updated jquery function to iterate over array of JSON objects. Logs recognize JSON values as intended!

```
$(function() {
          $('a#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/background_process', {
              input_search: $('input[name="input_search"]').val(),
            }, function(data) {
                $.each(data.result, function(index, element) {
           console.log(element.recipeName);
                    });

            });
            return false;
          });
        });
```

Changed yummly_search() by getting rid of jsonify function to:

```
return json_obj['matches']
```

Comment: `yumly_search()` shouldn't call `json.dumps()`, since the controller is calling `jsonify()`. You're encoding the data as JSON twice.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I have changed the code and getting: [object Object],[object Object], ...  result in browser.

Comment: You've got an array of objects. You need to iterate over the array and access the properties that you want to display in the result.

Comment: Thank you so much - I was stuck on this for a week, how can I give you credit for this answer?

Comment: I haven't written an answer because the question doesn't say what it wants the output to be from that JSON object.